# Character is not displaying properly in page

Tags: html, jsp

On gmail login page there is language selector drop down.

When i copy and pase same html `<option>` from gmail web page source to my page it display characters like `?????????` inside my drop down.

Why? I have set charset `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in my jsp page. Here is the header of my page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">        
    </head>
    <body>

<select>
  <option value="ja">
  ‪日本語‬
  </option>
  <option value="zh-CN">
  ‪简体中文‬
  </option>
  <option value="zh-TW">
  ‪繁體中文‬
  </option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code or fiddle is better.

Comment: What are the HTTP headers of your page, and what is its actual character encoding?

Comment: I updated my question for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

**Tip**: Always add the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
    <body>
    <select>
      <option value="ja">
      ‪日本語‬
      </option>
      <option value="zh-CN">
      ‪简体中文‬
      </option>
      <option value="zh-TW">
      ‪繁體中文‬
      </option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Works!!